# Delete s specific value column from all tables

Tags: sql, oracle

To call all the tables I am using:

```
select * from cat
```

to delete a value like for example customer_nr = 10000 I am using:

```
delete from customers where customer_nr = 10000;
```

But how can I delete this specific value from all tables?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM cat` just gets the value for all the columns of the `cat` table - it does not get the values from all tables.

Comment: How would Oracle know what you want to delete in each other table? Surely the other tables do not all have a `customer_nr` column and even if they did why would Oracle know that the `customer_nr` in one table should be deleted when you delete it from another table; and if they don't have a `customer_nr` column then how can you determine what to delete?

Comment: there are about 30 tables. In 3 of them are the customer_nr = 10000. I have to delete them.

Comment: `DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_nr = 10000` then `DELETE FROM other_table1 WHERE customer_nr = 10000` then `DELETE FROM other_table2 WHERE customer_nr = 10000`

Comment: I am looking for something like delete from "all tables" where customer_nr = 10000;

Comment: That syntax does not exist.

Comment: so I cant tell oracle sql to get a specific value from all tables and delete them?

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for something like `delete from "all tables" where customer_nr = 10000;`

You cannot delete from all tables using a single SQL statement.

The safest method is to explicitly delete all the items from each table separately:

```
DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_nr = 10000
DELETE FROM other_table1 WHERE customer_nr = 10000
DELETE FROM other_table2 WHERE customer_nr = 10000
```

You could do it with dynamic SQL (but please don't - one day it will go wrong and you will delete values that you did not intend to).

Something like:

```
DECLARE
  cmds SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  SELECT 'DELETE FROM ' || owner || '.' || table_name || ' WHERE customer_nr = 10000'
  BULK COLLECT INTO cmds
  FROM all_tab_columns
  WHERE column_name = 'CUSTOMER_NR';

  FOR i IN 1 .. cmds.COUNT LOOP
    -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( cmds(i) );
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE cmds(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

But please - don't.